# How can I use Heroku's scheduler to run jobs in a 2X sized dyno?

Tags: heroku, scheduled-tasks

I would like to use Heroku's [scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-size) addon to run a job on a  [large size Heroku dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler). Is this possible? and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible however it's high on the requested list of features for 2X dynos and Heroku is looking into it.

Comment: Thanks for status update. As an aside for anyone else coming to this question - you *can* run one-off command line jobs with 2X dynos. So a work around for the current lack of scheduler support is to run a cron job on another server that invokes the job.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku now supports choosing your dyno size on Heroku Scheduler (see [Heroku Documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) )

> On the Scheduler Dashboard, click “Add Job…”, enter a task, select a frequency, dyno size, and next run time.

This feature was added June 6th, 2013 (see [Heroku Changelog)](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/273)